# Flickr api - call photo sets

Tags: flickr

I have API key and API secret and i have downloaded the recent library 3.1.

When i use the example mentioned, i get public photos. And the library i am using included this file `phpFlickr.php` which has all methods.

I am now trying to access the photo sets api, which is not returning anything. And the document says there is no other authentication that is required. please check the code below

```
require_once("phpFlickr.php");
$f = new phpFlickr("56cc01317fdce40c31c8f66498746c4d");
$sets = $f->photosets_getList();
```

Answer (score 0):

@sandy : If you want to show flickr slider gallery in your website then you can use pictobrowser its best way to display flickr and Piccasa albums on website.

Using PictoBrowser one can easily embed Flickr and Picasa photostreams in anywebsite. All you need is follow few simple steps given here.

```
- visit http://pictobrowser.com/
- Click PictoBuilder at the top left corner of the page.
- Enter your Flickr/Picasa username.
- Choose images/ albums.
- Set Tag or Groups.
- It outputs some HTML code
- Copy that HTML code and paste it in your website or blog.
```

Comment: but this is not dynamic right, for ex: if a new set is added then we cannot add it.

Comment: Its totally dynamic you can add new photos its automatically updated in to the set. If you want to change set then you have to generate new embed code for new set.

Comment: ya then, that will be problem for me right....we wont be knowing if they add new sets which needs to be displayed in website...